# Node.js - replace() - заменить неизвестное число на другое

Tags: node.js

Есть у меня строка:

> Онлайн: 10/456

Нужно переодически заменять эту строку на

> Онлайн: (переменная)res/(переменная)res

Как это сделать, если я не знаю, какое число будет на момент замены?

Comment: Использовать регулярное выражение `\d`

Comment: А нельзя использовать обычное присвоение?

Comment: «Есть у меня строка» — где есть? Что мешает заменить целиком старую строку на новую строку с нужным содержимым? Непонятно ничего